# Azure, Active Directory: how to create new user

Tags: azure

I am trying to create a new user on Azure using the initial default domain name. I found under domain names which is: `myemailwithoutchars.onmicrosoft.com`.

I also tried `myemailwithoutchars@onmicrosoft.com` and got this error:

> Invalid characters or syntax for user name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a new user named "ABC" on an active directory named "MyAD". Give the name as abc@myad.onmicrosoft.com. Please check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-users-create-azure-portal) for more information